# Wordpress redirect logged in users from various pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have no clue about coding, which will become obvious in a second. I found this code here, which works fine:

```
    function add_login_check()
    {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(6005) ) {
    wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
    exit;
    }
    }

    add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

I just wonder, how i can make this apply to several pages (IDs), e. g. 6005 and 6003 and 6013 etc. How would I properly "write" that?

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `is_page()` with a single ID (6005) but it will also accept an array of IDs to test against. Checking multiple pages is simply a case of passing in an array of IDs instead of a single value.

Example:

```
function add_login_check() {
    $page_ids = array( 6005, 6003, 6013 );
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( $page_ids ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'mydomain.com/my-member-area/' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'add_login_check' );
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Dear Nathan, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for. THANK YOU!